# How can a miner pack more transaction in one block?

Tags: transactions, gas, mining, pending-transactions

Other than lowering the gas price and increase the gas limit, is there any simple configuration change to ensure the miner increase as many transactions as possible until the block is almost full?

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, miners can change it via a setting.
Please read https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6ehp60/recommendations_to_miners_to_change_gas_limit_and/#ampf=undefined for more information on it.